# Windows Home Server as inline firewall with remote access

Tags: remote-desktop, proxy, monitoring, windows-home-server

I have a DSL modem connected to Windows Home Server (WHS) 2011 on a HP ProLiant Microserver N40L. This is connected on one NIC as the "red" line in and named Internet. A 2nd NIC on the HP server, named LAN (my "gren" line), is connected to my Ethernet and Wireless router with all other home PC's and devices connected to it, mostly via wireless.

So I have the WHS server setup inline, thus all internet traffic going through it. I have two questions from here:

1. I could access the server via remote desktop before when all PC's, including the server, were simply connected to the router. Now that the server is on its own NIC, I can no longer remote desktop to it from any PC on the 2nd LAN NIC. How do I fix this?
2. What can I use on the Windows Home Server, now that it is inline, to monitor internet usage per device on my network? I've got Squid's Windows build but not sure how to set it up as a transparent proxy on WHS. Besides, it just does logging and needs additional apps like SARG reports to pull out the usage stats. From my research it doesn't seem like there is any reliable Windows build for Sarg reports. Isn't there a Windows based solution for internet usage reports?

UPDATE: I managed to remote desktop to the server from my LAN using the IP of the new NIC instead of the server name. Not ideal but it works. So now the main outstanding issue is the 2nd part of my question re. internet usage logging.

UPDATE: Added diagram 
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What errors do you get for remote desktop?

Comment: Before adding the 2nd NIC to the home server, it was on the same network within the same IP range so then I could remote desktop to it using the machine name. Now that it is in a different IP range the name resolution doesn't work anymore. I've also noticed that when connecting to it via its main IP from the onboard NIC, the remote desktop session is pixalted with blotchy block on screen on unresponsive. When I remote desktop to the new IP of the 2nd PCI Express NIC added, it works as before, but I can not use the server name anymore.

Comment: You could use [Network bridging](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-network-bridge#1TC=windows-7) to create an aggregate network from the two NICs. You should pay attention to have only one DHCP server on the unified network.

Comment: Thanks but not sure that is a good idea due to MS warning as follows: "You shouldn't create a bridge between an Internet connection and a network connection because it creates an unprotected link between your network and the Internet, which makes your network accessible to anyone on the Internet." That is exactly what I would be doing in my case.

Comment: The server is currently as exposed to the Internet as it will be then, so, for it, nothing will have changed. Nothing will have changed also for the other devices when they connect to the Internet as they do now. The router is still the best firewall you have, as long as you don't poke holes in it with port forwarding, and your local network is still distinct from the Internet. This warning is only meaningful if the server is directly connected to the Internet, to avoid fusing the local network with the Internet. If the server is compromised, the attack will propagate anyway via the other NIC.

Comment: You are basically just fusing two home networks, both exactly as secure as their their fusion will be.

Comment: The server connected to the DSL modem is not regarded as a connected directly to the internet? I added diagram to original post for clarity.

Comment: The DSL modem also connects to two NICs: One to the Internet and the other to the local network, and bridges between the two. Differently from the above suggested bridging, It rather *translates* packages from one to the other. The Internet and local networks are not fused, so that the modem has one IP address on the Internet and another on the local network. This allows the modem to also supply services such as firewall and DHCP, and this is why local computers are unreachable from the Internet unless the router does port forwarding with IP-address translations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36964/discussion-between-neville-and-harrymc).

Comment: I have added this as an answer, since I don't see any other solution that applies in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Network bridging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridging_%28networking%29) to aggregate both internal networks from the two NICs
into one internal network.
You should pay attention to have only one DHCP server on the resulting unified
internal network.

Microsoft's [instructions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-network-bridge#1TC=windows-7) are :

> A network bridge is software or hardware that connects two or more
>   networks so that they can communicate. You can create only one network
>   bridge on a computer, but one bridge can handle any number of network
>   connections.
>
> 1. Open Network Connections by clicking the **Start** button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking **Control Panel**. In the
>      search box, type **adapter**, and then, under Network and Sharing
>      Center, click **View network connections**.
> 2. Hold down the Ctrl key and select each network connection that you want to add to the bridge.
> 3. Right-click one of the selected network connections, and then click **Bridge Connections**. Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the
>      password or provide confirmation.

This is not a security risk in your case, since you are basically just fusing
two home networks, both exactly as secure as their their fusion will be.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try this on the weekend to see if this solves the secondary issue of the name resolution over my network. For now remote desktopping via IP is fine. Any ideas on the main question though of setting up the inline proxy with internet usage monitoring?

Comment: I don't think monitoring these kinds of stats from a single PC is easy. Your router is in the middle of everything and is more logical for that. See for example [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/222740/how-to-the-monitor-the-bandwidth-and-data-usage-of-individual-devices-on-your-network/) for DD-WRT, or [this one](http://nextgendigitalhome.com/using-the-tomato-firmware-to-monitor-bandwidth-by-ip-address/) for Tomato.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting,

Although having a Squid transparent proxy is a good starting point if you want to monitor browser behavior.. You will have a more accurate picture of monitoring "actual data usage" if you consider setting up WMI, or SNMP on the networked devices or server. With WMI or SNMP, You can poll counters for practically anything from networked devices to include interface information (total tx/rx).  There are opensource solutions which can then provide this information graphically. Just to name a few of them, Zenoss and MRTG may potentially be beneficial within your setup.

Good luck to you, Hope you find this post useful.

Comment: This sounds super complicated but will go do some reading up on your above suggestions. If I have to do any specific setup per device, then that is not going to be a solution for me as that is too much effort for home use and the devices themselves may possibly not all support that type of setup.